# Cannot find symbol IllegalArgumentException

Tags: java

I have a very simple program that tries to throw an exception. The compiler says it cannot find `IllegalArgumentException` even though it didm't say anything about that name when I put it in the throw specifier part:

```
import java.lang.*;

class A
{
    public A() throws IllegalArgumentException
    {
        if (n <= 0)
            throw IllegalArgumentException("n is less than 0");
    }
}
```

Here's the error:

```
Main.java:28: error: cannot find symbol
            throw IllegalArgumentException("n is less than 0");
                  ^
  symbol:   method IllegalArgumentException(String)
  location: class A
1 error
```

I realize this is very simple (my very first attempt at writing Java). I've tried looking for answers but they haven't helped me to a solution.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Use the new keyword

```
public A() {
    int n = ...;
    if (n <= 0) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("n is less than 0");
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Also, do I *have* to have `throws X` when I am throwing something?

Comment: Not for [runtime exceptions](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/runtime.html) :)